# iText - how to do search/replace on existing RTF document

Tags: c#, itext, mailmerge

Currently I'm working on a simple Mail-Merge module.

I need to load plain *.RTF template, then replace all words enclosed in [[field]] tags and at the end and print them out.

I found the iText library which is free and capable of loading/saving pdfs and rtf.
I managed to load rtf, merge a few copies to one huge doc but I have no idea how to replace [[field]] by  custom data like customer name/address.

Is that feature present, and if yes - how to do it?
The solution platform is c#/.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I decided to use *.docx and "Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office" .NET strongly typed wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that pdf is the way you want to go.

According to [this article](http://itext.ugent.be/library/question.php?id=48) it is extremely difficult at best and not possible at worst.

Would something like [RTFLib](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/dev/rtflib.html) work better for you?

G-Man

Answer (score 0):

You can use RichTextBox control to find/replace placeholders.

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox(); 
rtb.LoadFile("template.rtf");
string placeHolder = "[[placeholder_name]]"; 
int pos = rtb.Find(placeHolder); 
rtb.Select(pos, placeHolder.Length);
rtb.SelectedText = "new value";
```

After this you can get rtf formatted text with:

```
rtb.Rtf;
```